# How to add the COM reference for Excel 2016 in visual studio 2015?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2015, interop, excel-2016

I wanted to make a windowsforms project in my visual studio 2015 which I just downloaded. Now I want to read and write in an Excel file, so I was thinking about to use interop for it. Now I got Excel 2016 downloaded on my desktop and i got the .NET framework 3.5 and 4.6 installed. But when I try to add a reference and search in "COM" or "Assemblies" I cant find the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel anywhere...

How to do this?

Thanks in advance,

wouter

Answer (score 0):

I had to download the Office developer tools..

Link to those: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/office-tools/